# Как правильно записывать данные из json в инфоблоки в 1c-Bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет.

Подскажите как сделать проверку что бы не дублировались элементы в инфоблоке при каждой перезагрузки страницы и еще мне бы хотелось чтобы в инфоблоках были только те элементы которые находятся в json.

Здесь я получаю данные из json и записываю их в массив

```
    $url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    use Bitrix\Main\Web\HttpClient;

    $httpClient = new HttpClient($options);
    $httpClient->get($url);
    $res = $httpClient->getResult();

    try {
        $ar = json_decode($httpClient->getResult(), true);
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        echo 'Ошибка: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }

    $json = [];
    foreach($ar as $item){
       $json[] = [
          "id" => $item['id'],
          "name" => $item['name'],
          "username" => $item['username']
       ];
    }
```

Добавляю в инфоблок элементы полученные данные из json

```
      foreach($json as $student) { 

                CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
                $el = new CIBlockElement;

                $PROP = array();
                $PROP[1] = $student['id'];
                $PROP[2] = $student['name'];
                $PROP[3] = $student['username'];

                $arLoadProductArray = Array(
                    "MODIFIED_BY" => $USER->GetID(),  
                    "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => false,        
                    "IBLOCK_ID" => 1,
                    "PROPERTY_VALUES" => $PROP,
                    "NAME" => $student['id'],
                    "ACTIVE" => "Y",  
                    "PREVIEW_TEXT" => "",
                    "DETAIL_TEXT" => "" 
                );

             if($PRODUCT_ID = $el->Add($arLoadProductArray)){
                    echo "New ID: ".$PRODUCT_ID;
             }
             else{
                    echo "Error: ".$el->LAST_ERROR;
             }

       }
```

Так уже вывожу элементы инфоблока

```
    $ib = [];
        if(CModule::IncludeModule('iblock')) {
            $arSort= Array("NAME"=>"ASC");
            $arSelect = Array("ID","NAME", "PROPERTY_ID", "PROPERTY_NAME", "PROPERTY_USERNAME");
            $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 1);

            $res =  CIBlockElement::GetList($arSort, $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);

        while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
            $arFields = $ob->GetFields(); 
            $ib[] = [
                "id" => $arFields['PROPERTY_ID_VALUE'],
                "name" => $arFields['PROPERTY_NAME_VALUE'],
                "username" => $arFields['PROPERTY_USERNAME_VALUE']
            ];

        }

    }

foreach($ib as $student) { 
    echo $student['id'], ' ';
    echo $student['name'], ' '; 
    echo $student['username'], ' '; 
}
```

Comment: Записывайте ID студента из json в XML_ID элемента инфоблока. перед добавлением делайте гетлист по XML_ID => jsonIDs (иденты студентов). Добавляете только те элементы, которых у вас нет. т.е вы их не нашли по XML_ID

Comment: И отдельный совет) Не используйте свойства без надобности. Например NAME элемента = имени студента, CODE элемента равен юзернейму, а XML_ID равен иденту из json. В таком случае не придется извращаться с выводом. Это применимо только в случае если вы не строите планы на эти свойства

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переработал ваш код с учетом своих комментариев. Кажется должно работать)

```
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;
use Bitrix\Iblock\ElementTable;
use Bitrix\Main\Web\Json;
use Bitrix\Main\Web\HttpClient;

Loader::includeModule('iblock');

$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

$httpClient = new HttpClient($options);
$httpClient->get($url);
$res = $httpClient->getResult();
$iBlockId = 1;
$jsonData = [];
$excludedIds = [];

try {
    $ar = Json::decode($httpClient->getResult());
} catch (\Exception $e){
    echo 'Ошибка: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

foreach($ar as $item){
    $jsonData[$item['id']] = [
        "id" => $item['id'],
        "name" => $item['name'],
        "username" => $item['username']
    ];
}

$testIds = array_keys($jsonData);
// делаем запрос, чтобы узнать что у нас уже записано и складируем 
// существующие иденты в переменную для дальнейшей проверки
$elementIterator = ElementTable::getList([
    'select' => [
        'ID',
        'XML_ID',
    ],
    'filter' => [
        'IBLOCK_ID' => $iBlockId,
        'XML_ID' => $testIds,
    ]
]);

while ($element = $elementIterator->fetch()) {
    if (in_array($element['XML_ID'], $testIds)) {
        $excludedIds[] = $element['XML_ID'];
    }
}
//если в исключенных идентах мы не видим текущего - добавляем новый элемент
foreach ($jsonData as $student) {
    if (!in_array($student['id'], $excludedIds)) {
        $newElement = ElementTable::add([
            'MODIFIED_BY' =>  $USER->GetID(),
            'IBLOCK_ID' => $iBlockId,
            'NAME' => $student['username'],
            'CODE' => $student['name'],
            'XML_ID' => $student['id'],
            'ACTIVE' => 'Y'
        ]);

        if (!$newElement->isSuccess()) {
            echo $newElement->getErrorMessages();
        } else {
            echo $newElement->getId();
        }
    }
}
//собираем и выводим
$printData = ElementTable::getList([
    'select' => [
        'ID',
        'NAME',
        'CODE',
        'XML_ID'
    ],
    'filter' => [
        'IBLOCK_ID' => $iBlockId,
    ]
])->fetchAll();

foreach ($printData as $data) {
    echo $data['XML_ID'], ' ';
    echo $data['CODE'], ' ';
    echo $data['NAME'], ' ';
}
```